# node GC scavenge allocation failure

Tags: node.js, garbage-collection

What are the difference between "task" and "allocation failure" in these lines (end of line)?

```
5:13:36 PM worker.1 |  [33809:0x7ff6fa04d000]  1810211 ms: Scavenge 167.9 (175.1) -> 167.2 (175.1) MB, 0.9 / 0.1 ms  (average mu = 0.981, current mu = 0.926) task;
 
5:13:48 PM worker.1 |  [33809:0x7ff6fa499000]  1814585 ms: Scavenge 77.2 (80.6) -> 76.6 (80.6) MB, 1.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.984, current mu = 0.945) allocation failure;
```

Are "allocation failure" really means a failure for my app, is it normal to have this?

Comment: The tag at the end is what triggered the `Scavenge` minor garbage collection. An `allocation failure` is part of the normal operation of the generational garbage collector and by itself is not an indication of a failure with your app.

Comment: An answer is a bit longer as it requires some detail of what the v8 garbage collector does, this is a good overview: https://v8.dev/blog/trash-talk

Comment: Reading this about "generational pattern", I have the feeling that tuning the gc interval for each app is important, to separate correctly young / old objects. Am I right?

Comment: v8 is amazingly good at what it does 99% of the time. It is general purpose though,  will resize itself based on workload, and caters to web browsers too, so there are always apps and workloads that can trip it up. You will usually see more benefit reducing object allocations in your app than messing with the GC.